# Can GitHub render Zeppelin notebook?

Tags: github, apache-zeppelin

With Jupyter notebook (`ipynb` file), when I commit the file into GitHub, GitHub can render my notebook quite nicely: commands + all output of the commands.

However, GitHub doesn't render Zeppelin notebook (JSON file) nicely, it just shows the JSON text file content. Is there a way to view Zeppelin notebook in GitHub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As illustrated in [`hortonworks-gallery/zeppelin-notebooks`](https://github.com/hortonworks-gallery/zeppelin-notebooks), you need to use a thrid-party viewer to see those files, which are not directly supported by GitHub:

> Generate a link to preview the notebook by pasting the url from #1 into ZeppelinHub viewer (https://app.zepl.com/explore).
> This will generate a preview page for your notebook (at a url that looks something like https://www.zepl.com/viewer/notebooks/aHR0cHM6Ly9yYXcuZ2l0aHVidXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tL2hvcnRvbndvcmtzLWdhbGxlcnkvemVwcGVsaW4tbm90ZWJvb2tzL21hc3Rlci8yQTk0TTVKMVovbm90ZS5qc29u/)

Comment: It looks like the viewer has been moved to https://app.zepl.com/explore

Comment: @FrankSullivan Thank you. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Github cannot do so natively, as seen here:
https://github.com/hortonworks-gallery/zeppelin-notebooks/blob/master/2A94M5J1Z/note.json

There is a plugin for Google Chrome to facilitate this, but it is not working at the moment.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apache-zeppelin-github-vi/nmcclabkicmehbdlfnmlgdbihinlldhc?hl=en-US